# Главный и заглавный

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Главный - это понятно, тот, кто возглавляет что-то, является лидером и т.д. А вот "заглавный" чаще всего говорят о буквах (но не только). Какая разница между этими словами?
Поскольку тут приветствуется собственное мнение, предположу, что в случае буква речь идет не о слова "глава", "главенствовать", а о слове "заголовок". Но это не все объясняет - ведь заглавная буква далеко не всегда находится в заголовке текста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слово "заглавный" употребляется не только в сочетании "заглавная буква", но и в понятии "заглавная роль", которое означает роль, связанную с заглавием произведения. К примеру заглавная роль в трагедии "Гамлет" - роль Гамлета, а главные роли - короля, королевы, Офелии и т.д. То же в трагедии "Ромео и Джульетта"...

Answer (score 1):

"Заглавная буква" – это термин. Вот так говорится, и всё тут. Еще есть "заглавная роль", это не то же самое, что " главная роль". Других значений слова "заглавный" с ходу и не помню.